# display asterisk instead of no value in password field

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html, web

I would like to display asterisk instead of no value in password field. 
When I am setting up the field as type=text then I can see the plain text. When I set the type as password then I am getting blank field.
Is there a way to display the value as asterisks?

```
  <input type="text" id="txtPwd" runat="server" />
```

This is the field I have.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Maybe it's time to update your browser, as mine shows the password fields just like expected -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/X38tJ/)

Comment: Maybe I didnt get something in your question but why you cant just add a fake value to the input type="password" to display asterisk ?

Comment: Are you trying to replace the characters with asterisks as the user types them?

Comment: Why are you not using `type="password"`? why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute:

```
 <input type="password" placeholder="●●●●●●●●●">
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AJ2kn/

Answer (score 2):

If you want the user's text input to be replaced by asterisks you *need* to use a `password` input—a `text` input just won't do it:

```
<input type="password" id="txtPwd" runat="server" />
```

However, the default value will be blank (this applies to `text` input as well). If you want to initialize this to a default value, you can do it like this:

```
<input type="password" value="dummy" id="txtPwd" runat="server" />
```

*Note: I highly recommend **not** putting a users' password as the default value of a password field! It may compromise your users' password.*

If you want to display some asterisks as placeholder text when the field is empty you can do that with with the `placeholder` attribute (again, this applies to `text` input as well):

```
<input type="password" placeholder="*****" id="txtPwd" runat="server" />
```